# Design bug in flag dialog

Tags: bug, design

Finally, a bug that seems reproducible.

When opening the flag dialog in Chrome for iOS (iPad, not iPhone - iOS version 8.3 - Chrome 43.0.2357.56, 32-bit), the "moderator intervention" reason text box overflows the dialog:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a feature to me. :)

Comment: @HDE226868 - iPhone or Pad? I'm on a Pad.

Comment: No red circle drawn with Paint? :(

Comment: @Lohoris I suppose I should...

Comment: Yes please, Paint is important, don't make it cry

Comment: @Lohoris does that make you/it feel better?

Comment: @ArtOfCode it makes many people feel better, I'd say the whole Internet would be a tiny bit happier.